# Why Facebook Like button load large js files?

Tags: javascript, facebook, performance, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-like

To integrate Facebook Like button, I included a piece of js code according to Facebook Developer guide, but found it loaded several js files, and in total, it consumes 273kb which is even larger than my SPA js.
Could anyone explain this and advice on how to reduce it?

Thanks a lot!

[image]

Comment: *"how to reduce it?"* Don't implement it?

Comment: Isn't this a question better aimed at facebook? It's not like we have any control over their documentation or processes...

Comment: @Shadow I was thinking it was me mis-configured something in the plugin. Sounds like the only thing I can do is to remove it from my page. Something worth reading: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/why-16-of-the-code-on-the-average-site-belongs-to-facebook-and-what-that-means-68956cd731be

Comment: I guess the good news is that I would assume the bulk of that would be set up with decent caching rules, probably even across sites. So it's likely that at most they'll only take the brunt of that on first page load...